# Не работает отправка данных в БД MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Есть текстовая форма:

```
<form action="/send1.php" method="post" id="1">
  <p>
    <b>Код<b></br>
    <textarea name="c" cols="40" rows="3"></textarea>
  </p>
  <p><input type="submit" value="Выполнить"></p>
  <p><input type="submit" 
            onclick="this.form.action='/send2.php';document.getElementById('1').submit();" 
            value="Отправить и выполнить"></p>
</form>
```

С открытием форм проблем нет. Появилась проблема со второй формой. Её код:

```
<?php
  $code = $_POST['c'];
  if (!$code) {
    $code='false';
  } else {
  }
  echo("<script>$code</script>");
  exit();
  $mysqli = new mysqli("сервер", "пользователь", "пароль", "ещё раз пользователь");
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("An error has occured: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
  }
  $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO SANDBOX(code) VALUES ($code);");
  if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO SANDBOX(code) VALUES (?);")) {
    $stmt->bind_param("s",$code);
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
  }
?>
```

При этом, в таблице SANDBOX есть две колонки: code и id (unique, auto increment).

Проблема заключается в том, что скрипт выполняется, однако данные не попадают в таблицу, и не высвечиваются сообщения об ошибках.

При этом, во всех остальных случаях (однако в этих случаях в таблицах была только одна колонка) код такого плана работал весьма успешно.

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: А ничего что у вас тут `exit();`?

Comment: Убрал exit(),спасибо, признателен.

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы выводились ошибки, надо перед коннектом написать

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Плюс убрать лишний вызов prepare.

Ну и exit тоже убрать